# Is there any way in sailsJs to run all cron jobs in its own thread?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have sails application with 20 cron jobs each taking around 4-5 seconds to complete. Whenever multiple cron jobs run at same time the route APIs calls are effected. Is there a way to run each cron in different threads

Answer (score 0):

Simple like that - no. You would need to create CRON job outside your Sails app and run it separately from Sails.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sails.load`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-load) in scripts to load Sails app. Schedule scripts through system's crontab.